# FME Reading SLD problems

Tags: fme-form, xml

I am trying to parse an SLD file (which is XML) and generate a CSV output based on the rules within it. The following is a sample of the SLD structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>Standard style</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Line</Title>
      <Abstract>Line Style</Abstract>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>Line - 1:0 to 1:4,000</Name>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>code</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <MinScaleDenominator>0</MinScaleDenominator>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>4000</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <LineSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#FF00FF</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.3</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-dasharray">1.5 0.8</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>      
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

The output I am trying to create is

```
Title, Abstract, RuleName, FilterProperty, FilterValue, Min, Max, Type, StrokeColour, StrokeWdith, StrokeStyle

Line, Line Style, Line - 1:0 - 1:4,000, code, 2, 0, 4000, Stroke, #FF00FF, 0.3, 1.5 0.8
```

I add a standard XML Reader using the Feature Paths

[image]

And the use the Elements to Match set to the Rule which is what I am interested about

[image]

Which works but does not expose all the attributes I need. It seems to expose the Stroke/CSSParameter as a list {}.

[image]

At this point I thought I should be using the XMLFlatterner or the XMlFragmenter but both do not export a list object.

I have read a number of the FME Tutorials but still unsure how I should 'flattern' the StrokeCSSParameters for each Rule.

Using FME 2020 64Bit on Windows.